# Wrong boolean mapping using left join fetch

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 5.6.4.Final with Spring Boot and MySQL 8. The application is fetching a record containing a boolean attribute. It's mapped as a 'bit(1)' in MySQL. This works everywhere except when I'm using a distinct and a left join query. The boolean is always mapped to true.

```
// Caller
billRepository.findByMemberId(Long.parseLong(memberId))

// Repository
@Query("select distinct b from Bill b LEFT JOIN FETCH b.items item where item.memberId = ?1")
List<Bill> findByMemberId(long memberId);
```

Now when I just insert a findAll() before, the boolean mapping fixes itself.

```
// Caller
Iterable<Bill> allBills = billRepository.findAll();
return billRepository.findByMemberId(Long.parseLong(memberId));
```

In other places the boolean mapping works fine but I'm not using a distinct left join query there.

I tried to migrate the column to a tinyint(1) unsigned. Then it works correctly but I would have to migrate all columns. Also the Hibernate dialect "suggests" a bit(1) upon schema generation.

**Update**

```
select distinct bill0_.id                    as id1_0_0_,
                items1_.id                   as id1_1_1_,
                bill0_.amount                as amount2_0_0_,
                bill0_.bill_sent             as bill_sen3_0_0_,
                bill0_.cash_ctrl_id          as cash_ctr4_0_0_,
                bill0_.due_date              as due_date5_0_0_,
                bill0_.first_reminder_sent   as first_re6_0_0_,
                bill0_.member_address_id     as member_12_0_0_,
                bill0_.open                  as open7_0_0_,
                bill0_.reminder2cash_ctrl_id as reminder8_0_0_,
                bill0_.reminder_cash_ctrl_id as reminder9_0_0_,
                bill0_.second_reminder_sent  as second_10_0_0_,
                bill0_.sent_state            as sent_st11_0_0_,
                items1_.amount               as amount2_1_1_,
                items1_.bill_id              as bill_id9_1_1_,
                items1_.cash_ctrl_id         as cash_ctr3_1_1_,
                items1_.from_inclusive       as from_inc4_1_1_,
                items1_.member_id            as member_i5_1_1_,
                items1_.text                 as text6_1_1_,
                items1_.to_exclusive         as to_exclu7_1_1_,
                items1_.type                 as type8_1_1_,
                items1_.bill_id              as bill_id9_1_0__,
                items1_.id                   as id1_1_0__
from bill bill0_
         left outer join bill_item items1_ on bill0_.id = items1_.bill_id
where items1_.member_id = ?
```

**Driver version**

```
runtimeOnly group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.31'
```

Comment: What version of MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver are you using? As of Connector/J 8.0.19, TINYINT(1) SIGNED should map to java.lang.Boolean. This was an unexpected change for some users (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100309) but it might be just what you want in your case.

Comment: Could you log the sql requests built by hibernate ?

Comment: @BillKarwin I've added the current version which is higher than the one you mentioned.

Comment: @PierreDemeestere I've added the generated SQL.

Comment: Does the not well mapped boolean field belongs to Bill or Item ?

Comment: @PierreDemeestere to Bill